# Why disposable object was copied before setting it instance to null?

Tags: c#

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        Stream copyOfStream = this._stream;
        this._stream = null;
        if (copyOfStream != null && !this._leaveOpen)
        {
            copyOfStream.Close();
        }
    }
    this._stream = null;
}
```

Why in the code above was created copy of `Stream` instance before setting `this._stream` to `null`?

For example why not this:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        if (this._stream != null && !this._leaveOpen)
        {
            this._stream.Close();
        }
    }
    this._stream = null;
}
```

Comment: Who wrote that code? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Microsoft [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs,8bbe8b9f33dee290](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs,8bbe8b9f33dee290).

Comment: I suppose the idea was to prevent NullReferenceException if multiple threads call Dispose at the same time.

Comment: Thread-safety. At the time you (try to) call `Close()`, another Thread could have set it to null.

Comment: Is that more efficient than using a lock?

Comment: This code is making my head hurt. Too much inside knowledge about how things work. A dispose method should `Dispose` other `IDisposable`s... not have enough knowledge to magically *know* that `Close` will be enough for any stream.

Comment: @nvoigt Well the documentation for `Stream` does say that `Close()` calls `Dispose(true)` so it looks like they are implementing the IDisposable pattern where you have a `protected void Dispose(bool)` method. But in that case, why not just call `Dispose(true)` directly? Unless `Close()` does extra work - but it REALLY SHOULDN'T!

Comment: You need a 1-800 support phone number to write code like this :)  Never write code like this yourself, you really do want to get the releaseHandleFailed MDA since it is an excellent diagnostic for really broken client code.  It is not done consistently, compare to StreamWriter.Dispose().